# MongoDB Atlas Cannot get console mode 6

Tags: mongodb, console, whitelist, mongodb-atlas

I get this error in my terminal whenever I try connecting to MongoDB Atlas. Actually, I have my IP whitelist to 'Allow access from anywhere'. I don't know why i'm getting this problem.

I also tried:

```
$ mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-cueit.mongodb.net/test" --username <usrnm> --password <pwd>
```

but it gives me different error.

> It looks like this is a MongoDB Atlas cluster. Please ensure that your
>   IP whitelist allows connections from your network.

Comment: The `It looks like this is ...` message is displayed for _any_ connection error if the url contains ".mongodb.net".  There should have been some other error messages that indicate what actually went wrong.  If not, try using `--verbose`

Answer (score 0):

It should be active and 0.0.0.0/0  (includes your current IP address) under Network Access